# Call a method in another Component that returns some value in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I am having two independent components in react and I want to call a method in first component that returns Some value to another component.

```
import React from 'react';
export default class A extend React{
    constructor(props){
     super(props);
    }

    getName = () =>{
       var name = "MyName";
       return name;
    }
    render(){
      //Some code to render
    }
}
```

Now In component B in want to call method getName() so that it returns name,which i want to use in component B.

```
import React from 'react';
export default class B extends React{
    constructor(props){
     super(props);
    }
    getName = () =>{
      //Want to call the getName method of component A here
    }

    render(){
      //Some code to render
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you use redux or context inside your project? maybe you can pass it via it?

Comment: how do you render these two components?

Answer (score 1):

Use React lifting State Up.

Here is the official documentation.

[Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: but we don't know how OP is rendering these compoents.

Comment: You can keep the value in the parent component's state and pass it to both child components. Then you can keep a function to update the value of that particular state variable in parent and pass it down to component A so when when you update the value in component a it will call the fucntion which is passed down as prop from parent component to component A which will update the value in parent component. and will get reflected in both the child. I will add a sample code, which I guess will work for you.

Comment: **Please copy it to a text editor**

`import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import A from './A';
import B from './B';
export default class Parent extend Component{
  state = {
    data: 0,
  }

  updateData = (data) => {
    this.setState({data});
  }

  render () {
    const {data} = this.state;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <A data={data} updateData={this.updateData} />
        <B data={data} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}`

Comment: **Please copy it to a text editor**

_**Component A**_

`import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class A extend Component{

  updateData = () => {
   const {data, updateData} = this.props;
    updateData(data);
  }

  render () {
    const {data} = this.state;
    return (
        <div onClick={this.updateData}>{data}</div>
    );
  }
}`

Comment: **Please copy it to a text editor**

_**Component B**_

`import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class B extend Component{

  render () {
    const {data} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>{data}</div>
    );
  }
}`

Comment: Can you try this and let me know?